# MySQL Slow Query despite EXPLAIN shows less rows

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am using MySQL 5.1.34, all tables were in Innodb Engine.

I have 3 tables as below:

```
TableA (1M rows)
-ID (Auto Increment PK)
-TableB_ID
-Date varchar(indexed)
-Other Fields

TableB (60M rows) 
-ID (Auto Increment PK)
-TableC_ID
-Other Fields

TableC (10M rows)
-ID (Auto Increment PK)
-Other Fields
```

My objective is to join 3 tables which matching the "date" in TableA. The "date" column is indexed and a simple WHERE clause can be complete within second. E.g.

```
SELECT * FROM TableA where date = '2015-03-13';
10000 rows in set (0.1 sec)
```

However when I try to join TableB and TableC with the SQL below, the process become extreme slow.

```
SELECT A.*, C.Something FROM TableA A JOIN TableB B on A.TableB_ID = B.ID JOIN TableC C on B.TableC_ID = C.ID WHERE A.date = '2015-03-13';
10000 rows in set (20 sec)
```

I've tried to troubleshoot the slowness using EXPLAIN Command, output as follow.

[image]

What could be the reason? Please help!

Comment: Is `A.TableB_ID` and `B.TableC_ID` is indexed ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty EDITED. Sorry, Yes both A.TableB_ID and B.TableC_ID is indexed.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath What do you mean by disk seeking?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty . . . The `id` columns in `B` and `C` are primary keys, both as the OP says and as shown in the `explain`.  There is no need for additional indexes.

Comment: @PeirHwa.Soo . . . How long does the query take the second time you run it?  You might have a cold-cache issue, where reading the the approximately  20,000 pages from disk into memory takes time.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The second time to run the same query complete almost instantly. It appears that the result was cached in the second execution, the query will be slow again if I run it after a couple of minutes.

Comment: @PeirHwa.Soo . . . The solution to your problem is to allocate more memory to the page cache/buffer pool.  Or getting a bigger server and allocate more memory to the page cache/buffer pool.

Comment: @GordonLinoff This is an old database server, but we have already allocated 16gb memory to the buffer pool, the matching rows are only ~10k it shouldn't required more resources.

Comment: (some simplification) Your select gets 12k lines from 1M rows. For each of those lines it has to get 1 line out of 60M row table and then another one from 10M row table. And even though there are some optimizations under the hood,and you're using PKs it still requires considerable work. Have you tried narrowing down the results from first table to see if it has an impact on query time?

Comment: And one long shot (hence just comment). Try adding Index (ID,TableC_ID) to TableB and (ID,Something) to TableC. That might (and it might need optimizer hint to use these indices) help the engine to get it faster. Especially if TableB and TableC have long rows.

Answer (score 0):

As I said, it's probably a disk seeking issue. As you measured, once the records are in the memory, the query is fast, which, to me, confirms the issue.

Fetching a random location from the disk takes about ~10ms as the disk head has to move. The relevant records are probably clustered on the disk and the server had to do approx. 20s/10ms = 20.000 seeks.

The are a couple of obvious approaches:

- Use an SSD. No seeking.
- Add enough RAM to the server to avoid disk access, or use a dedicated server for these queries (16GB looks like more than enough (though I don't know the size of the records) so I guess there are other frequently used massive tables).
- Cache the result per date - and store it in a database (memcached/redis/..). This could work really well if the records are static for the old dates as you don't have to worry about cache invalidation.

Anyways, it's probably good idea to do some back-of-the-envelope calculations and figuring out the memory requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You have left out a lot of important information by not providing `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, but I will make some guesses.

Are you really fetching 10K rows?  What are you going to do with all of them?  It takes time to get that many rows.

If you are using MyISAM, then B would benefit greatly from `INDEX(ID, TableC_ID)`.  InnoDB should not benefit from it, unless the table is quite 'wide'.

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%';` How much RAM do you have?

Is the Query cache in use?  If it is, that would explain why it was so fast the second time.  Most production system find it better to have the QC turned off.